# JFreeChart BarChart -> NO gradient

Tags: java, colors, jfreechart, bar-chart

my bar chart is always drawn with a gradient color by default. I just want a simple color **without any styled effects**.

Can anyone help ?

Code:

```
   final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
        "",         // chart title
        xLabel,               // domain axis label
        yLabel,                  // range axis label
        dataset,                  // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
        true,                     // include legend
        false,                     // tooltips?
        false                     // URLs?
    );

  final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
  // SOMETHING HAS TO BE DONE HERE

  showChart(chart); // Simply shows the chart in a new window
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste your code. In the most cases you should add some code to make it gradient like: GradientPaint

Comment: +1 for the realest title. Web 2.0 goodbye!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem lies in the `BarPainter` you are using. The JFreeChart version 1.0.13 default is to use `GradientBarPainter` which adds a metallic-ish look to the bar. If you want the "old" look the solution is to use the `StandardBarPainter`.

```
final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
((BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
```

That should do it.

Alternatively, if you want use JFreeChart's `BarRenderer`, you could force it to use the `StandardBarPainter` by calling the static method `setDefaultBarPainter()` before initializing your renderer.

```
final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
BarRenderer.setDefaultBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
((BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new BarPainter());
```

If you want more control of the chart you can always build it from the ground up instead of using `ChartFactory`, but that does require a lot extra code.

Comment: Great! I was looking for the solution for a long time!

Comment: Kudos for the solution. The "default" (I think) bar chart has this very cheap look.

Answer (score 8):

Before you create the chart from ChartFactory you can set the chart theme:

```
ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createLegacyTheme());
```

The default is the JFreeTheme which adds the gradient. The following themes are available:

```
ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createJFreeTheme());
ChartFactory.setChartTheme(StandardChartTheme.createDarknessTheme());
```

Comment: This solution helped me in case of using StackedBarChart which was not affected by changing barPainter in renderer. Perhaps I was accessing wrong renderer. Nevertheless this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1-source.html) for an older version of [`org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) shows how to set the series colors. Just specify plain colors instead of gradients.

```
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.green);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.blue);
```

Correction: The key to @Jes's helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092567/230513) may be found in the initialization of [`defaultBarPainter`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.java#L161) in `BarRenderer`.

Comment: Does not work too, still everything is drawn with a gradient. Unfortunately i can not upload an image yet :( Furthermore the what will happen with at the upper solution if there are more than three columns ?

Comment: An image would be good, but the code would be better. If you do nothing, you should get the colors prescribed by the [`DefaultDrawingSupplier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html).