# Drawing bar chart that looks like MS Excel equivalent

Tags: java, excel, jfreechart, bar-chart, java-2d

Is it possible to create bar graphs in Java which has the same look and feel like the way we create bar graphs in MS Excel?

It is not possible to add the difference between the two graphs i.e. one created using JFreeChart (using Java)  and the other created directly in MS Excel  since I am not able to paste the two graphs here.

Please let me know if its possible and using which API.

[image]

the above link is for bar graph drawn using java
[image]
 the above link is for bar graph drawn in ms excel

You can see the difference.

Comment: *"since i am not able to paste the two graphs here."*  Upload them to an image upload site and provide links.

Comment: Or you know, upload them here.

Comment: @Chris  The OP does not have enough rep. to upload images.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for in the look and feel? jFreeChart is quite customizable so what doesn't it do that you need?

Comment: DYM like seen above?  (From [Wiki How](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelcharts/ss/bar_graph.htm))

Comment: can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: So what are you wanting? Dates at the bottom? The fancy bars? The missing key to the right?

Comment: @TimB i want the bars to look simple there should be no graphics.

Comment: @Andrew,@TimB please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was google "jfreechart bar chart style" and that found me the first result:

[JFreeChart BarChart -> NO gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076305/jfreechart-barchart-no-gradient)

You could have found the answer yourself with a simple google search in a fraction of the time than you spent nagging us to do it for you.