# Remove White color strip on the left side of bar in stacked bar chart in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

Can anybody help me to Remove White color strip on the left side of bar in stacked bar chart in *JasperReports* please. Need solution as soon as possible and bars are on exactly on the line please click this url for screen shot

[image].

Please see this the customizer class i am using to set properties for stacked bar chart in *iReport*.

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();     
    CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator();

    /* Remove Bar Border*/
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);

    //Spaces between bars
    renderer.setItemMargin(0.05);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);

    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(false);

    CategoryAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setLowerMargin(0.02);
    axis.setUpperMargin(0.02);
}
```

I have used  "old" look  StandardBarPainter to remove the white strip but it is unable to set setBarPainter it is showing The method setBarPainter(StandardBarPainter) is undefined for the type BarRenderer.
 i am new to java plase help please find the below image to fix the error.[image]

Comment: code and any screen shots would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFreeChart BarChart -> NO gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076305/jfreechart-barchart-no-gradient)