# Bar chart using Jfreechart java

Tags: java, jfreechart

How can I get a bar chart with different bars having different initial value. What I am getting is that bars always start from x-axis taking same initial value for each bar. Isn't there a way such that bars can be lifted up from x axis so that each bar can have its corresponding initial value? I have data in which I have to show that some specific thing is happening from some initial time to final time.

[image]

In the image given, if I want the first bar to start from 125000.000, how can I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: A [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7082986/230513).

Comment: that didn't solve my problem.I want the bars to be uplifted from x axis

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the chart as shown.

Comment: the thing is that i want to show that a particular instance of CREATE VM from say 124000 to 133000.So i want the part from 120000 to 124000 to be deleted.Can i do that?

Comment: I want to show range of values.The values on y axis are timestamps,so i want to start a particular bar from any point not the x-axis.

Comment: Is there any way to delete part of a bar or color it with different color so that i can infer that the values start from some point on the y axis not from initial fixed value that is 120000.000.

Comment: You can change the axis lower bound, but it will hide some bars.

Comment: But then it will change lower bound for all the bars

Comment: I want to have different lower bound for each bar

Comment: As far as I know, that's not supported.